# What is the best way to separate an improper integral with three conflicting points

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to study the convergence of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(\pi x)|}{x^{\alpha}|1-x|^{\beta}}dx$ with $\alpha,\beta>0$. Correct me if I'm wrong but there is also the conflicting point $x=1$ that could make the integral of study divergent. So, to study it's convergence we would have to split it in the sum of four other integrals whose integrands only have one improperty each
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{1}^{2}f(x)dx+\int_{2}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
my main question is if we could split the original improper integral in the sum of three integrals instead of four.

So for an improper integral with $n>2$ conflicting points we would have to split the integral in $n+1$ points.

Comment: Why are we splitting at $x = 1/2$ and $x = 2$?  Your definition of improper integral should have permitted discontinuities at either or both endpoints and zero discontinuities in the interior of the interval of integration, so $\lim_{\ell \rightarrow 0^+, m \rightarrow 1^-} \int_\ell^m \cdots \,\mathrm{d}x + \lim_{m \rightarrow 1^+, r \rightarrow \infty} \int_m^r \cdots \,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: You only have to split the integral at singularities and its okay for either of them to be the endpoints  of the integral. The improperness requires slight deviations from standard integration like approaching the singularity from a specific direction. So you only need two integrals here.